# Closed terms in formula prove / disprove

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

**Question:**
Prove/disprove: If the formula $\exists x \alpha$ is valid then there exists closed terms $t_1, t_2$ s.t $\alpha(t_2/x)\vee \alpha(t_2/x)$ is logically valid.

**My answer**

I think this is false, because a statement can be valid in a signature with only one element in the domain (so there doesn't neccesarily exist 2 closed terms, there's a case where only one exists. 
I'd like to verify my thoughts on this.

Comment: With *valid* do you mean *logically valid*, i.e. true in every structure ?

Comment: Closed *terms* need individual constants; thus, it seems to me that the answer depends on the existence of individual constants in the language. If the language has no constant, we have no closd term, and thus the formula $\exists x (x=x)$, that is valid in every non empty structure has no quantifier-free equivalent sentence.

Comment: What Mauro said. If there are no constants, there are no closed terms. The theory might be valid only in infinite models — number of terms and size of models don't correlate.

Comment: That's a very nice point, but the question doesn't say that $t_1$ and $t_2$ are distinct. And as the other comments say you need to need to know more about the language to answer the question. So the question you have been posed is an unfair question: it is neither provable nor disprovable given the information supplied.